# MySql copy profiling data to table

Tags: mysql, profiling

I want to copy profiling data to a table I create in MySql.
I want the table to contain the exact data that I get from the command SHOW PROFILES;

For example, if I have this:

```
mysql> show profiles;  
+----------+------------+--------------------------------+  
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                          |  
+----------+------------+--------------------------------+  
|       16 | 0.00059700 | select * from imprumuturi      |  
|       17 | 0.00042050 | select * from imprumuturi      |  
|       18 | 0.00042000 | select * from imprumuturi      |  
|       19 | 0.00042950 | select * from imprumuturi      |  
|       20 | 0.00048050 | select * from imprumuturi      |  
+----------+------------+--------------------------------+  
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I will create a table that has 3 columns (queryid,duration and query), and I need a command that will copy those 5 rows from "SHOW PROFILES;" to my table.

`insert into table (show profiles);` does not work

I need it to be done in MySql alone, no other tools/patches.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: I get this: 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that bcorresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show profiles)' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO t (SELECT [some columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/profiling-table.html) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING)

Comment: What is the column that gets me the query text?

Comment: I don't know because I don't have profiling enabled so I can't see it. You need to look at your profiling table "SELECT * FROM PROFILING LIMIT 1" to find out.

Comment: I have done that before posting here, but there isn't a column that shows me the query text :|

I only have the query id, and I need to get the text. If I had that, this would be solved.

Comment: I'm guessing it's related to some sort of log, where QueryID is the ID used there, but I can't figure out where. Good luck in your search. :)

Comment: Please let us know if you find it. It's good for the SO archives.

Comment: I will, but I am beginning to think this isn't possible (yet)...  
I have posted a question in the MySQL forums

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t (select * from information_schema.profiling)
```

Comment: That will not get me the data I want.
Your command will insert the different stages and their duration for all queries (I will get many lines per query, and I won't know the query text).
I want these columns: Query ID, Duration and Query.
And I need one line per query. Just like in my example.